# _tkinter.TclError: Item 1 1 not found

Tags: python, tkinter

i am triying to get boolean values from db and if True check icon comes in and 0 uncheck icon, but it looks like i cant loop over it in a correct way.. i have made a for loop that is connected with db but it shows empty.

```
def employee():
global email_field, checkfield

conn= sqlite3.connect('schoonschip.db')
cursorr = conn.cursor()
cursorr.execute("SELECT  email, rowid, selection FROM employee ")
employe = cursorr.fetchall()

trv.delete(*trv.get_children())

for i in employe:
    item = trv.item(trv.focus(i))
    print(item)
    if item['values'][1] == 1:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=i,  tags='check')
    else:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=i, tags='uncheck')

conn.commit()
conn.close()
employee()
```

Comment: Please show the full error that includes the line of code causing the error.

Comment: What do you want to do on the line `item = trv.item(trv.focus(i))` because you have already deleted all items in the treeview before the for loop?   Also `i` is a row from database and it is not a valid item ID used in `trv.focus()`.

Comment: I want to filter all the rows if they got selection boolean true, if soo then get check icon...

Comment: File "C:\Users\ugurc\Desktop\werk\schoonschip.pyw", line 93, in employee
    item = trv.item(*trv.focus(i))
  File "C:\Users\ugurc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 1267, in focus
    return self.tk.call(self._w, "focus", item)
_tkinter.TclError: Item .......@gmail.com 1 1 not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the value of the `selection` column in the database table, you need to change the for loop as below:

```py
for i in employe:
    # i[2] is the value of 'selection' column in the result set
    if i[2] == 1:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=i, tags='check')
    else:
        trv.insert('', 'end', values=i, tags='uncheck')
```